# How to make a textbox of multiple line type in html?

Tags: php, html

```
<input class="FormElement" name="term" id="term"  type="text">
```

What modifications should I do to this textbox to make it multiple line, without the need to modify anything else in the code, like reading its value.

I used to read the input by javascript like that, what should be changed in that as well?

```
var $term = $("textarea#term").val();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTextareaElement) with the same `name`, so replace this:

```
<input class="FormElement" name="term" id="term" type="text">
```

With this:

```
<textarea class="FormElement" name="term" id="term" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
```

The `rows` and `cols` arguments are the width/height respectively...or use CSS styling to specify the size, like this:

```
<textarea class="FormElement" name="term" id="term" style="width: 200px; height: 40px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Now I can't read the input. I used to write:
var $term = $("#term").val(); 
But now it doesn't work!

Comment: @Ahmad - that should still work, do you have `id="term"` used in more than one place?